# Python for loop; print input into rows of 14. Random numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I have an assignment to write a program to read in an integer from the user, and use that number as the seed value. Next, generate 180 random numbers between 6 and 197, separated by "}". Print these out in rows of 14

```
import random


see= int(input("Please enter the seed value: "))
print(see)
random.seed(see)
for x in range (180):
        rand= random.randint(6,197)
        print(rand, end= "}")
        if x % 2 == 1:
            print()
```

The problem is the modulus operator is only giving rows of 2. I am using the modulus operator as that is the suggested method from my professor.

I am unable to figure out how to modify it to change it to print to rows of 14.

Comment: So put there 14 instead of 2. Modulus gives you rest after dividing, eg 0 % 14 = 0, 1%14 = 1 ...14%14 = 0, 14%15 = 1...

Comment: I tried that, it still gives a row of 2 instead of 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `mod` operation, you will always get an extra element on the first line, so change your initial range to `1, 181`. Also your `mod` should be 14 rather than 2.

```py
import random


see= int(input("Please enter the seed value: "))
print(see)
random.seed(see)
for x in range (1, 181):
        rand= random.randint(6,197)
        print(rand, end= "}")
        if x % 14 == 0:
            print()
```

Keep in mind that if the specified range (6-197) is 197 inclusive, your range should be `6, 198`.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I had tried changing to 14 before but it still only gave the two rows. Appreciate your help.

Now to try to understand why that worked lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

see= int(input("Please enter the seed value: "))
print(see)
random.seed(see)
for x in range(180):
  rand = random.randint(6, 197)
  print(rand, end= "}")
  if ((x + 1) % 14 == 0):
      print()
```